# Parse through a list and capture all values from one occurance to another

Tags: python, list, file

I have been working on a project for a bit now, and looking it over I think I am over complicating the issue for myself, so I'm looking for feedback on what the best method for accomplishing this problem might be.

The problem I am dealing with is I have a file with entries similar to this:

```
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSSL-20-116:00018DA4;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSUB-20-116:375;
V-1\ZDS\R\ESCN-20-116:1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO\N-20-116:3;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-116-1:0;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-116-2:4;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-116-3:8;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSSL-20-117:00018DA5;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSUB-20-117:376;
V-1\ZDS\R\ESCN-20-117:1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO\N-20-117:2;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-117-1:8;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-117-2:12;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSSL-20-118:00018DE1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSUB-20-118:380;
V-1\ZDS\R\ESCN-20-118:1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO\N-20-118:3;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-118-1:0;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-118-2:4;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-118-3:8;
```

What I am trying to do is read both files into a list in Python, and then parse through and find the EMSSL-20 value that matches. If one file has a match but the other doesn't, I want to report those differences. If I find a match in both files, I then want to compare the EMSUB, ESCN, and EMBO values in that EMSSL group.

So what I'm asking, is there a way to parse through a file or list until I find an EMSSL entry, and then record everything until I reach the next EMSSL entry?

I had originally gone with the approach of using regular expressions to filter the lists into just the items I wanted to look at, and while this works, I'm it compares all the EMSUB, ESCN, and EMBO values, rather than just those that belong to a specific EMSSL group.

I might be overthinking this issue, but I've been struggling with this for weeks so any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So what I'm asking, is there a way to parse through a file or list
> until I find an EMSSL entry, and then record everything until I reach
> the next EMSSL entry?

sure, you can read line by line and record in a sublist everyting until you find the line with the desire condition, then store said list in you result list and re-start your sublist...

Like for example

```
>>> data = r"""V-1\ZDS\R\EMSSL-20-116:00018DA4;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSUB-20-116:375;
V-1\ZDS\R\ESCN-20-116:1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO\N-20-116:3;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-116-1:0;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-116-2:4;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-116-3:8;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSSL-20-117:00018DA5;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSUB-20-117:376;
V-1\ZDS\R\ESCN-20-117:1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO\N-20-117:2;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-117-1:8;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-117-2:12;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSSL-20-118:00018DE1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMSUB-20-118:380;
V-1\ZDS\R\ESCN-20-118:1;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO\N-20-118:3;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-118-1:0;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-118-2:4;
V-1\ZDS\R\EMBO-20-118-3:8;"""
>>> 
>>> chunks=[]
>>> result=[]
>>> for line in data.splitlines():
        if "EMSSL-20" in line:
            if chunks:
                result.append(chunks)
            chucks = [line]
        else:
            chunks.append(line)

>>> result.append(chunks) # store the last chunk
>>> from pprint import pprint  # print things nicely 
>>> for item in result:
        pprint(item)
        print()
 
     
['V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSSL-20-116:00018DA4;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSUB-20-116:375;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\ESCN-20-116:1;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO\\N-20-116:3;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-116-1:0;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-116-2:4;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-116-3:8;']

['V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSSL-20-117:00018DA5;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSUB-20-117:376;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\ESCN-20-117:1;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO\\N-20-117:2;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-117-1:8;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-117-2:12;']

['V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSSL-20-118:00018DE1;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSUB-20-118:380;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\ESCN-20-118:1;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO\\N-20-118:3;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-118-1:0;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-118-2:4;',
 'V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMBO-20-118-3:8;']

>>>
```

now everything is in nice sub groups

Comment: That would be really helpful, but my values aren't stored in strings so I can't use the split method. Typically, these text files will have thousands of lines in them, so I was reading these files into lists to make them easier to work with. 

Is there a similar method for lists?

Comment: just substitute the `data.splitlines()` in `for line in data.splitlines():` for the appropriate thing, if your read from a file, them put the file handler there, (the one you get from open like in `file = open(...)` or with the *with* statement `with open(...) as file`) and do `for line in file:`, if you already have all the lines in some list then iterate over that list...

Comment: I did attempt that, but when substituting out the data.splitlines() with for line in file: it just outputs the contents of the entire file with no groupings or filtered content.

Comment: then the content of your file isn't like in your sample, and everything is in a single line, maybe you need to first split it on `";"`... or you're doing something weird... update your question and include some code and sample illustrative of your issue

Answer (score 0):

What I did that gave me the output I wanted was I used `groupby` from `itertools`and this allowed me to write the following class:

```
class SlashGrouper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.group_id = 0

    def __call__(self, text):
        EMSSL20regex = re.compile(r"^V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSSL-20-\d+:\d+\w*;$")
        EMSSL35regex = re.compile(r"^V-1\\ZDS\\R\\EMSSL-35-\d+:\d+\w*;$")
        
        emssl20 = re.findall(EMSSL20regex, text)
        emssl35 = re.findall(EMSSL35regex, text)
        
        if emssl20:
            self.group_id += 1
        elif emssl35:
            self.group_id += 1
        return self.group_id
```

I then created a separate function to create a new list with all the sub-lists divided how I wanted for each file:

```
def regFilter():
    """This function takes no arguments and returns a list of sublists which contain the groups 
        of EMSSL-20 and EMSSL-35 for both file 1 and file 2. 

    Returns:
        list: list of differences between the two files
    """
    # Group elements in file 1 by the EMSSL numbers
    file1_grouped = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(file1_filtered, key=SlashGrouper())]
    file2_grouped = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(file2_filtered, key=SlashGrouper())]
    
    # Pop the first indexed sublist containing all values before the first EMSSL match
    file1_grouped.pop(0)
    file2_grouped.pop(0)
    
    # Append all of EMSSL-20 and EMSSL-35 groups to a new list
    text1 = "EMSSL-20 and EMSSL-35 Groups - File 1"
    EMSSL_groups.append(text1)
    
    for line in file1_grouped:
        EMSSL_groups.append(line)
        
    text2 = "EMSSL-20 and EMSSL-35 Groups - File 2"
    EMSSL_groups.append(text2)
      
    for line in file1_grouped:
        EMSSL_groups.append(line)
           
    return EMSSL_groups
```

I went this route becasue I wanted to create sub-lists that started with the value I was looking for, instead of ending each new group with this value.

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it does run fast considering each text file has thousands of lines. Hope this can help someone else too!